# Magento MultiStores but only 1 site is index by Google?

Tags: multistore

There are two websites sharing in one Magento admin.
Two sites have their respective Magento Store
I added both of the sites on Google Webmaster Tools so Google can see that they are different sites.

Problem:
When I search on Google: *siteB2.com*, Google will display *siteA1.com*
I checked the cache and I am sure that Google is using the *siteA1.com* instead of the other.

Even if I tried search using: **site:siteB2.com**, still Google uses *siteA1.com* information. 
Basically, you will see the siteB2.com uses the correct URL but the title and the description are from siteA1.com - on search results.

What setting or code do I have to do to restrict Google from accessing the other website?

I tried searching on various pages but seems there are few documentation about this issue.

Comment: Are there any errors/warnings in webmaster tools for site B2.com ? It should be showing the no. of URLs indexed for that site, take a look there.

Comment: Is the content of site A and B the same? Also, check in the HTML what the value of the robots tag is